# Can I call a python script from emacs?

Tags: python, script

I have a simple python script:

```
$ cat ~/simple.py
import os
import sys


def write_greeting(inpath):
    outpath = os.path.splitext(inpath)[0] + '.txt'
    with open(outpath, 'w') as f:
        f.write('hello world!')
    sys.stdout.write('wrote {}!'.format(outpath))
    return None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    write_greeting(sys.argv[1])
```

For example, running

```
$ python ~/simple.py ~/path/to/foo.bar
```

creates a text file `~/path/to/foo.txt` reading `hello world!`. After `~/path/to/foo.txt` is created, the message `wrote ~/path/to/foo.txt!` is printed to `stdout`.

Now, say I'm editing a file `~/path/to/foo.bar` in `emacs`. I want to run `simple.py` on the file I'm currently editing from within emacs. After my script is called, I want to insert the contents from `stdout` where my cursor is.

Is this possible?

Essentially, I'd like to automate the sequence of commands:

```
C-u M-! python ~/simple.py ~/path/to/current/file/name
```

with a function `M-x my-python-script`.

Comment: Take a look at [`call-process`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Synchronous-Processes.html). Here's an [example usage](https://github.com/xiongtx/jdecomp/blob/master/jdecomp.el#L140-L145).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely possible:

```
(defun my-run-python-script-whatever ()
  (interactive)
  (insert (shell-command-to-string (format "python3 %s" buffer-file-name))))
```